# How to change the text color based on container background color?

Tags: flutter, widget, gradient, background-color, text-coloring

I have a container that has a gradient background color with some text. I am showing the percentage at the end of the container. Depending upon the percentage, Green color should be applied from left to right. When the percentage hit 100%, The whole container will become green.

Now I want to know that how to achieve the text color becomes white where the container color changes to green and vice-versa.

Note :
The text in the container and the percentage are from API.

I have attached image for reference below.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5NWt.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaQfG.png)

Answer (score 0):

in your case i think you can use something like this :

```
 Text(
                'text message',
                style: TextStyle(                   
                    color: ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor(_bgColor) ==
                            Brightness.light
                        ? Colors.green
                        : Colors.white),
              ),
```

for a complete guide try this [documentation](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-dynamic-text-color-based-on-background-brightness/#:%7E:text=1.,%3A%2080%2C%20color%3A%20_backgroundColor.)

Comment: Does it only work for all text? If it is like 50%, I assumed the view should be like 'lorem ips' is white and 'um dolor' should be green. That was the part blew my thought. Does it provide that?

Comment: it works ,but it depends on how the progress bar is made

Comment: @Mahdi Can you give me some examples? It's like **aoiTenshi** said. The container color changes depending on the percentage. So the text color should change according to the container color. But, the answer you gave changes the whole text color. Sorry, it seems I didn't explain well. I will edit the explanation.